# Session variable not storing in node.js

Tags: node.js, session, express

I searched and found a lot of similar problems with session variable being set to undefined, but none of the answers I found seemed applicable.

I have this function in my router file:

```
exports.loginHandler = function(req, res){
    username = req.body.username;
    password = req.body.password;
    readAccount(username, function(acct){
        if (acct.password = password){
            req.session.username = username;
            console.log(username+' logged in'+' pass: '+acct.password);
        };
    });
    res.redirect('/');
};
```

console.log executes just fine and both username and acct.password have the appropriate values. However, req.session.username just ends up being set to undefined.

Here's the readAccount function:

```
readAccount = function(user, callback){
    AM.login(user, function(acct){
        callback(acct);
    });
};
```

And here's AM.login:

```
exports.login = function(user, callback){
    accounts.findOne({username: user}, function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    callback(result);
    })
}
```

I'm guessing session variables can't be set under conditions, since this type of error doesn't seem uncommon.

Comment: have you actually set up session state storage for your application? AFAIK it does not come baked in.

Comment: It does come baked in with express, or at least it did for me. The problem was that res.redirect was executing before the variable could be assigned.

Comment: Ah, okay, I missed the express tag somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you're redirecting, which ends the response and saves the session, before you've set the `session.username` property. This is because `readAccount`, by way of `accounts.findOne`, is asynchronous and won't finish before `res.redirect()` is called.

You can ensure their execution order by moving the `res.redirect()` into the `readAccount` callback:

```
exports.loginHandler = function(req, res){
    username = req.body.username;
    password = req.body.password;

    readAccount(username, function(acct){
        if (acct.password = password){
            req.session.username = username;
            console.log(username+' logged in'+' pass: '+acct.password);
        };

        res.redirect('/');
    });
};
```

Also, be careful with `throw`'ing errors in asynchronous operations. The callback will have a different call stack than the starting function (e.g. `readAccount`), which makes `catch`ing errors difficult. This is why many APIs for Node pass errors as arguments instead.

Comment: how to access this variable at other places?

Answer (score 0):

Its short and easy method is write following line before sending response.

res.locals.session = req.session;

and your session will save the value of the varible.